# localhost request headers not sending cookies

Tags: ajax, node.js

I am building a nodeJS server which allows users to login using an AJAX post on a client application. The server responds with a cookie that, after successful login, keeps track of the user. I can't however seem to get the client application to send the cookie back to the server. It never seems to respond to the server including the cookie it just recieved.

On the fist call that's made to the server, I login with my credentials. the server responds with this:

**In the response headers:**

```
Set-Cookie:SID=0xtW36rYCiV; path=/; expires=Tue, 24-Jun-2014 14:14:51 GMT; secure
```

**In the subsequent request headers:**
    No cookie is sent back to the server

In my client application I am using the following code:

```
jQuery.ajax( {
            url: this.domain + this.url,
            async: this.async,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: this.dataType,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: true,
            accepts: 'text/plain',
            data: this.postVars,
            success: this.onData.bind( this ),
            error: this.onError.bind( this ),
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true                   
            }
        });
```

Note I am using the xhrFields.

And in my node server I am responding with this: (notice I am including all the CORRS variables)

```
if ( request.headers.origin )
{
    if ( request.headers.origin.match( /mydomain\.net/ ) || request.headers.origin.match( /appname\.mydomain\.com/ ) || request.headers.origin.match( /localhost/ )
                || request.headers.origin.match( /localhost\.com/ )
                || request.headers.origin.match( /localhost\.local/ )
                || request.headers.origin.match( /localtest\.com/ ) )
            {
                response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', request.headers.origin );
                response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS' );
                response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With' );
                response.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
            };
        }

        response.writeHead( 200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
        response.end( JSON.stringify( json ) );
}
```

I have also edited my windows hosts file to include these test domains so that I don't have to use an IP or localhost iteself:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       tooltest.com
127.0.0.1       localhost.com
127.0.0.1       localhost.local
```

But no matter what I do, or which of the above hosts I use, it never seems to work. It seems to only be related to localhost via ajax because if I go directly to the server url in question - it works.

**EDIT 1**

So for example - I open the client application and try to login to the server at foo.com/user/log-in. The headers for the request and response are as follows:

**Request:**

```
Remote Address:188.xxx.xxx.xx:7000
Request URL:https://foo.com:7000/user/log-in
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:undefined
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:45
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:foo.com:7000
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/animate-ts/trunk/bin/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
user:mat
password:testpassword
rememberMe:true
```

**Response:**

```
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 24 Jun 2014 14:14:21 GMT
Set-Cookie:SID=0xtW36rYCiV; path=/; expires=Tue, 24-Jun-2014 14:14:51 GMT; secure
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

As I undertand it, Foo.com has told the browser to store the cookie 0xtW36rYCiV. However when I make the very next request (foo.com/user/is-logged-in) to see if the user is logged in, no cookies are sent to foo. Foo.com looks for the cookie with the ID 0xtW36rYCiV but can't find anything. When I look at the 2nd request in dev tools I can see:

[image]

Does anyone have any other ideas? I thought I covered everything in the above, but im starting to think it just wont work :(

Thanks
Mat

Comment: Cookies set on a request to origin `X` are set *for origin `X` only* and no other origin, regardless of what origin actually sent the request. Subsequent requests to the cookie-setting origin should show the cookie, but subquent requests to other origins should *not* include the cookie. I'm not 100% clear if that's what is happening in your case, though, because I'm not clear which origins are getting which requests. Could you clarify that?

Comment: Alternatively, if that's not the issue you're encountering, is your request sent over HTTPS? Your cookie has the `secure` flag set, so it won't transmit over an unsecured channel. (Sorry for all the comments!)

Comment: Hi apsillers. Ive edited the question above with the use case to better illustrate. The server is in fact on a secure connection. Perhaps that's why its not working? Localhost is not secure?

Comment: I see that your first request is to `https://foo.com:7000`. Just to be 100% clear: your second request (with the missing cookie) is *also* to `https://foo.com:7000`? Also, I notice that your cookie expires 30 seconds after it is set -- are you performing the check quickly enough?

Comment: Any origin (including `localhost`) is "secure" (in cookie terms) if the request to it is done via HTTPS.

Comment: Yes that's correct - the client app sends both requests to the same server URL (first is https://foo.com:7000/user/login & https://foo.com:7000/user/is-logged-in ). And yes I've also checked the expiration. At the moment its 30 seconds (for testing) and that definitely works because when I test it outside the ajax call, using the URL directly, it works fine :/

Comment: any update on this? I'm having the same problem authenticating and then making additional calls to the server. (the cookie doesn't persist and it appears I've been logged out)

Answer (score 1):

My cookie isn't marked secure, and I'm facing this problem trying to send a GET request to my server (https://auth.mywebsite.com) from http://localhost:3000/.

I have the same auth flow as OP here.
First, sign in to auth.website.com, and receive back cookie in the response header:

```
set-cookie: Authorization=Bearer%20blahblah.blahblah.blahblah; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 05 Aug 2020 02:07:57 GMT; HttpOnly
```

Note, I don't have the `Secure` flag in `set-cookie`.

I noticed in Chrome devtools there was this warning that popped up when hovering over the `set-cookie` line:

"This Set-Cookie didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was defaulted to "SameSite=Lax," and was blocked because it came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation. The Set-Cookie had to have been set with "SameSite=None" to enable cross-site usage."

This might be the answer to my problem. But, I don't understand why this was working yesterday, but not today. No code has changed in between.

This issue occurs on both on Chrome and Safari.

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) has a good description of all the flags for `Set-Cookie`.

This is not a full answer, but perhaps some extra context for others facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but @aspillers commment lead to the solution for me. The cookie was marked secure, but I was doing the request over HTTP instead of HTTPS. Once I got my debugger switched over to HTTPS it started working.

Answer (score -1):

For chrome:

- Go to chrome://flags/
- Disable "SameSite by default cookies"
- Restart Chrome